# On bash script, julia issue?

Tags: bash, julia

I have written some test script for a new machine, but there's an issue that I don't know if it's julia itself or the way I am writting the script.

The julia program is just

```
module main_prog

println("Program to heat and test a new machine")
println("Does a lot of diagonalizations")

dim = 10
realiz = 5

for ii in 1:realiz
    A = randn(dim,dim)
    H = (A + A')/2
    eig_problem = eig(H)
end

println("End succesful")
end # module
```

And my bash script is

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 2`;
    do    
    mkdir job$i
    cp diagg_rmt.jl job$i
    cd job$i
    /home/user/julia/julia ./diagg_rmt.jl &
    cd ..
done
```

When I runt the script, it gives an strange error:

```
-bash-4.2$ ERROR: getcwd: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
in uv_error at ./stream.jl:1027
in pwd at ./file.jl:8
in abspath at ./path.jl:108
in _include_dependency at ./loading.jl:127
in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:296
in process_options at ./client.jl:280
in _start at ./client.jl:378
```

I have seen another posts of this happening in Ruby, for example, but no idea
what to do here. I am using CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

Comment: Not a bash problem. Verify with `bash -x /your/script/here`

Comment: It works for me, is this deterministic? Maybe a race condition, try using `&&` instead of `&` in line 7 of your bash sript, also what version of Julia are you using?

Comment: OR change the script call to `/home/user/julia/julia /path/to/juliaStuff/diagg_rmt.jl &` ? Good luck.

Comment: Strange, this works.

Comment: I'm going to add the comment of @user2820579 as an answer if that's okay?